# Iterate over array of strings and replace if exists

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am trying to iterate over an array of strings and check/replace if any of the strings exist in the input string. Using LINQ, this is what i have so far.

```
string input = "/main/dev.website.com"
string[] itemsToIgnore = { "dev.", "qa.", "/main/" };
string website = itemsToIgnore
                    .Select(x => 
                           { x = input.Replace(x, ""); return x; })
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

When i run this, nothing actually happens and my input string stays the same?

Comment: Maybe aggregate function is something you looking for. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Aggregate-Operators-c51b3869

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string website = itemsToIgnore
                   .Aggregate(input, (current, s) => 
                         current.StartsWith(s) ? current.Replace(s, string.Empty) : current);
```

and without Linq

```
foreach (var part in itemsToIgnore) 
{
  if (website.StartsWith(part))
  {
    website = website.Replace(part, string.Empty);
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i avoid with Replace matching on something like "should.", i only ever want to replace if i get an exact match with nothing in front.

Comment: May you explain your wish with some example?

Comment: If i have the string "should." noticed the "." after the word "should", and my itemsToIgnore list looks for "d.", it will catch replace the string "should." as "shoul". I only want to replace with an empty string if there is nothing in front of the itemsToIgnore list

Comment: I have made changes in answer for this case

Comment: So that fixed my problem but raises another issue. If my itemsToIgnore list equals {"d.", "red."}, and my input is "d.something.com", the StartsWith command returns false and doesn't replace it. Why is it ignoring my first item ?

Comment: You may use also current.IndexOf(s) == 0 if StartsWith prefers to behave so weird ). But firstly please try to add StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase as a second parameter of StartsWith call.

Comment: Tried both options and the 'd.' in my example is not stripped, it works if i remove 'red.' from my list of things to ignore

Comment: I'm shocked. Try to rewrite Linq statement in ordinar C# (I've added an example) and debug in carefully.

Comment: The foreach loop works and should the linq but thanks overall

Comment: The issue is due to the ordering of items in my 'itemsToIgnore' list, depending on how my input string looks, i may miss an item with the 'StarsWith' command. For example, with an input string = "d.q.takethis.off.com", if 'q.' is the first item in the ignoreList, the StartsWith wont catch it. I need to find a way to isolate each piece using startswith and go through the list over again on each replace